# Факториалы элементов списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, python-2.x

Нужно вывести факториалы в таком виде:

```
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120.
```

Вот код:

```
f = 1
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for k in list:
  for i in range(1, k+1):
    f *= i
  print(str(k) + '!' + ' = ' + str(f))
```

Как написать правильно?

Comment: А этот код написан неправильно? В чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

for item in myList:
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1, item+1):
        fact = fact * number
    print ("{}! = {}".format(item, fact))

1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

for i in range(1, 6):
    print(f"{i}! = {math.factorial(i)}")
```

---

*Примечание:*

Для Питон 3.6+ - в других нужно вместо *f-строки* применить метод `.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fact = 1

for i in range(1, 6):
    fact *= i
    print(f"{i}! = {fact}")
```

Comment: Решение более оптимизировано, чем все остальные ответы

Comment: @Philippe, да, но нужны именно факториалы элементов списка, то есть это необязательно последовательность от 1 до 5

Comment: @Anton_tr010 да, но важно понимать, что так можно

Answer (score -1):

Немножко осложнённый подход для тех, которые такие любят:

```
import itertools, operator

PARMS = (1, 6)

for i, j in zip(range(*PARMS), itertools.accumulate(range(*PARMS), operator.mul)):
    print(f"{i}! = {j}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Ошибкой в вашей программе является *слишком осложнённый цикл в цикле*

```
for k in list:
  for i in range(1, k+1):
    f *= i
```

Достаточно его заменить за простой:

```
for k in list:
  f *= k
```

Comment: А что, если список не последовательный